# Rate Limiting Feature for particular Route in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the below code that implements Rate Limiting feature for all Routes in a Group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'throttle:2']], function () {
    Route::get('/CSR', array('uses' =>  'CSR_Controller@index', 'as' => 'CSRList'));
    //Second Route
    //Third Route
    //Fourth Route
    //Fifth Route
    //....
});
```

**Question**
This works great. Is there any way to implement this for any particular route in a group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. Any attribute you can assign to a route group can be assigned to a single route as well (in fact route groups really only apply their attributes sequentially to each of the routes contained within them, nothing more). So you can assign a middleware group such as `api` to a single route:

```
Route::get('/route/path', ['middleware' => 'api', 'uses' => 'Controller@action']);
```

Or if you want to use just the throttling middleware you can use:

```
Route::get('/route/path', ['middleware' => 'throttle:2', 'uses' => 'Controller@action']);
```

For more details on the rate limiting feature you can check out the Laracasts video linked below:

> [What's New in Laravel 5.2: API Rate Limiting](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/2)

Comment: Rate Limiting Feature is for particular IP address or it will be valid for all visitors of the website. I meant, Let's say in stackoverflow.com site some page is restricted to be visited 10 times per minute. Let's say you visited 10 times and now when I will try to visit that web page I will not be allowed because per min 10 attempts are made. Is that correct ? Or I will be given 10 attempts separately ?

Comment: The limiting feature uses a number of request parameters (including the IP address), in fact the middleware uses the [`Request::fingerprint`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L841-L846) method to generate a unique key that is used for throttling (you can see there what parameters it uses to generate the fingerprint). This [Laracasts Video](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/2) explains nicely how the rate limiting middleware works.